# Complexity - input length

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I'm currently learning complexity (or efficiency however you call it), and I read about it in a book I got.
There is written something which I find pretty senseless and I need an explanation. I've tried looking online but I didn't find an answer for this certain example that they're giving.

> For an algorithm that gets the max number in a single-dimensional array the size of `n` the input length would be `n`.
>
> "For an algorithm that gets the max number in a two-dimensional array the size of `n*n` the input length would still be `n`."

I don't understand why the input length would be '`n`' in both cases even though for the two-dimensional you have to go through `n*n` numbers...
It says

> input length = the amount of work done ...

doesn't make any sense to me.
**Would anyone care to explain?** They certainly don't explain this there.

Comment: How have they defined the `input length`? Write the definition precisely as per the book in your question.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful Indeed, and i had written it. "input length is the measurement that indicates the work load of an algorithm" - roughly translated from hebrew... i don't study this material in english.

Comment: Then, how is the work-load defined as per the book? Is it the number of elements to be considered as input, OR is it the complexity in calculating the largest element in that array?

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful The workload is the number of operations that the computer does. for example: "if (h<1)" is one operation. "int n = 10" is another operation. the count of operations add up to be the workload.

Comment: Maybe this may help you ---> http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~avrim/451f11/lectures/lect0908.pdf . I feel they assumed the number of elements of 2d-array in totality to be `n`, else it is not possible to be done in O(n) complexity. I maybe wrong though.

Comment: Without more context from your book, we can't tell you what it means.  But I suspect the point you are misunderstanding is that, for purposes of input length, the book does *not* count `n` as the length of one side of a 2D array; instead, it counts `n` as the total size of the data.

Comment: @comingstormv i edited the post a bit. to make the size of the arrays clearer. it seems as though they meant that checking an array size n*n and and array size n would be the same input length.

Comment: As with many things in mathematics, it's up to you how to define input length, it's just that some definitions are more useful than others. I probably wouldn't define the length of an `nxn` matrix as `n`, but it may depend on the situation.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful From what i understand they said the array size n*n would make the same input length as checking the array size n. that's what i just don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a common misconception (much seen here on SO) that the complexity of a scan across a 2D array with `n*n` elements is `O(n^2)`.  It's not, it's `O(n)`.  A scan is a linear operation, one element after another.

The 2D array is a polite fiction, it is really just a convenience for accessing a 1D array.  After all, in languages which implement arrays properly (i.e. none of this array of pointers to blocks of memory) a 2D array is just a set of adjacent memory locations.  And even in languages which do implement 2D arrays as arrays of pointers they're just linear segments of memory with interruptions

If a scan across a 2D array were `O(n^2)` then you could magically transform it to `O(n)` by ignoring the 2d-ness and just scanning the underlying 1d block of memory.

`O(n^2)` describes a different complexity class of operations such as those in which each pair of elements in the input is operated upon.

Comment: If you defined the size of an `nxn` matrix as `n`, then scanning all the elements would indeed be `O(n^2)`. However such a definition isn't terribly useful, the size of an `nxn` matrix is better defined as `n^2` for the reasons you've given.

Comment: What you say makes sense, if the book wasn't using the same variable. although, the book used the same `n` as for both single dimensional array and two-dimensional array. from what i understand is if `n = 2` then the input length for 4 operations and 2 operations is the same. - just that it doesn't make sense. **Unless** they didn't mean the actual same `n` but just used the same letter..?

Comment: @YuvalRoth I think you can safely assume that it was a mistake for the book to use the same variable name. It's still correct, but it makes it harder to understand what they're trying to say.

Comment: @biziclop Just to make sure i understand. you can say `O(n^2) == O(n)` because they're both linear?

Comment: @YuvalRoth O(n^2) != O(n)

Comment: @YuvalRoth: that's precisely what you can't say !  `O(n^2)` and `O(n)` identify two different complexity classes.  And it's precisely because a scan of a 2D array is in the same class as the scan of a 1D array that they both belong to `O(n)`.  A scan is linear (`O(n)`) in the number of elements scanned.  The mistaken conclusion you have drawn about the equality of two different complexity classes arises directly from muddled thinking about how to count the size of the input to an algorithm.  Entirely forgivable in a newbie.

Comment: In big-O notation, n is simply the size of the input, which in this case is an nxn matrix. They are different uses of 'n'

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Well, i think i understand that, but if  i want to check a two-dimensional array the size of 2x2 the input length would be 4, correct? since you can think of it as just one big row of 4 numbers..?

Comment: @YuvalRoth Yes, the input length of a 2x2 array is 4. At least that's the standard (and sensible) way of looking at it,

Comment: I don't agree with this answer. Yes, sometimes there's ambiguity what "n" refers to -- and the size of the input is often assumed when talking about complexity (especially in the some contexts). But to say scanning an n*n matrix has O(n) complexity is wrong -- there's no room for interpreting "n" to mean "size of input" here -- it's given as the width and height of the matrix.

Comment: @PaulHankin Big-O notation allows a lot of wiggle room ("cheating") when assigning an algorithm a complexity class. For instance O(2n) represents linear growth and thus can be generalized as O(n). O(35000) represents constant time complexity and thus can be generalized as O(1). "n" in big-O notation is ALWAYS the size of the input. In this case that input is an nxn matrix. This does NOT imply O(n*n). The variable name used to define the input has no bearing on what "n" means in Big-O notation

Answer (score 0):

Reading in the comments that this book is written in Hebrew I would assume that the issue is a translation error or some other error in proofreading.  The definition given in the comments of input length "input length is the measurement that indicates the work load of an algorithm" doesn't match what you would assume the term means at all in English.

To answer the question about complexity, they are reusing the variable 'n' in multiple places which makes it slightly confusing.  They use 'n' to describe the dimension of the array and to describe the complexity.  O(n) simply means the complexity is linear to the input.  O(n^2) would be an exponential complexity.  In this case with an array of n*n elements the input is n*n or n^2, but the complexity of the algorithm is still O(n) (or linear).  This is because the algorithm still only operates on each input element once, whether the input is n or n*n.  It would still be linear if it operated one each element 2 or three times as 3n and n are both linear functions (any x*n would be linear).

I hope this helps.

Comment: `...O(n^2) would be an exponential complexity...` ---> No, it won't be!

Comment: yeah, exponential is more like O(c^n)

Answer (score 0):

Big-O notation is used to classify TYPES of algorithms (complexity classes), not necessarily how much time it will ACTUALLY take to run. For instance O(cn) is just O(n) where c is a constant.

n is the size of the input whether that input is an nxn matrix or just an 'n' length array. The big-O 'n' and the program variable name are not referring to the same thing.

Comment: I should also point out that @High Performance Mark is correct. I only posted to clarify a small thing where there seemed to be some confusion.